# how to update openssl 0.9.8 to 1.0.1 in easyphp

Tags: openssl, composer, easyphp

I am really new to this, and I am not sure how I should approach this. I am trying to download `composer` to my `easyPHP-webserver`, but enable to run composer I need newer openssl. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't EasyPHP itself have 'updates'?

Comment: how do I do that? Do you mean I should update easyPHP to the latest version and it will update the openssl?

Comment: Since OpenSSL was installed as part of EasyPHP in the first place, yes, I'd assume so.

Comment: thanks, grawity. it works, would you mind to post your answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, the OpenSSL libraries are bundled with EasyPHP – so the easiest option would be to **update the entire EasyPHP bundle**. (Considering how old 0.9.8 was, I'd say it's about time.)

---

Standalone [Win32 OpenSSL](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) versions can be downloaded as well, but this only works for minor version changes (e.g. 1.0.0 to 1.0.1). There have been several ABI changes between 0.9.8 and 1.0.x, so if you try to simply drop in newer `.dll`'s, your programs will crash.